# JQuery : .dialog() not working for next element of .classe selector

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I use a php while loop to generate some items with a litle description.
Each item has the same class and are preceded by an image of it.

The objective is to open a dialog that contains the description of the item when I click on the corresponding image.

This is what I've done:

Generate all items with all pictures:

```
        while($result = $req->fetch()) {?>
                <img src="./css/images/icon/<?=$result['category']?>/<?=$result['rarity']?>" alt="<?=$result['object']?>" title="<?=$result['object']?>" class="obj">
                <p class="descr_obj">
                    Name : <?=$result['objet']?><br><br>
                    Rarity : <?=str_replace(".png", "", $result['rarity'])?><br><br>
                    Description :<br>
                    <?=$result['description']?>
                </p>

        <?php }?>
```

Generate JQuery dialog:

```
$(".descr_obj").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    })

    $(".obj").click(function(){
        text = $(this).next(".descr_obj").text();
        $(text).dialog("open");
    });
```

But nothing is appearing and the console doesn't show any error...

Can you please, help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues.  The main one is that you never actually tell the dialog to open (by using `.dialog("open")`.  The second one is you're going to end up with a ton of dialogs - one for each `img` because you're repeating the paragraph.  Each instance of the `descr_obj` class will get it's own.

Try something like this (my php sucks, so it's probably wrong):

```
while($result = $req->fetch()) {?>
    <img src="./css/images/icon/<?=$result['category']?>/<?=$result['rarity']?>" 
         alt="<?=$result['object']?>" 
       title="<?=$result['object']?>" 
       class="obj" 
   data-name="<?=$result['objet']?>"
 data-rarity="<?=str_replace(".png", "", $result['rarity'])?>" 
   data-desc="<?=$result['description']?>">
<?php }?>
<p class="descr_obj">
    Name : <span class="name"></span><br><br>
    Rarity : <span class="rarity"></span><br><br>
    Description :<br>
    <span class="desc"></span>
</p>
```

But here is what it the JavaScript would end up looking like:

```js
$(function() {
    let dialog = $(".descr_obj").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });

    $(".obj").click(function() {
        for(let prop of Object.keys(this.dataset)) {
            dialog.find(`span.${prop}`).html(this.dataset[prop]);
        }
        dialog.dialog("open")
    });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fDk5.png" data-name="one" data-rarity="Super Rare" data-desc="Amazing" class="obj">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBUJX.png" data-name="two" data-rarity="Common" data-desc="Meh" class="obj">
<p class="descr_obj">
Name : <span class="name"></span><br><br>
Rarity : <span class="rarity"></span><br><br>
Description :<br>
<span class="desc"></span>
</p>
```